# Get leaderboard to update every time user score updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, leaderboard

I've managed to get the [leaderboard gem](https://github.com/agoragames/leaderboard) working on my Rails app at the moment but I can't seem to figure out how to get the user data onto it. I also don't know how to get it to update as the user score updates...

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/leaderboards-rails/) to try and get it working but am now struggling getting the last bit integrated...

At the moment I have the Boards update_service.rb like this:

```
module Boards
  class UpdateService < Boards::Base
    def execute(user)
      name = user.first_name
      score = user.percentages
      leaderboard.rank_member(name, score)
      member = leaderboard.score_and_rank_for(name)
      member[:page] = leaderboard.page_for(name, leaderboard.page_size)
      member
    end
  end
end
```

I want to call this service on all the users now (so that they are all ranked with their current scores) and then to set it up so that this is called every time the user's score is updated.

I don't know where to call it to get the initial data...

But by playing around in the rails console I have found calling this works:

```
update = Boards::UpdateService.new
Student.all.each do |student|
  update.execute(student)
end
```

For it to update as the user's score updates I thought I should do something like this:

```
 after_update :update_rank

  def update_rank
    Boards::UpdateService.new
  end
```

In the User class although to be honest I got this partially from the tutorial and I don't really understand why it's not:

```
def update_rank
  Boards::UpdateService(user)
end
```

But that could just be because I really don't understand what's going on very well...

Answer (score 0):

Because `UpdateService` is a class, not a method name, you have to create an instance of this class by invoking a constructor `UpdateService.new`. Seeing how there is an `execute` method there, consider doing something along the lines of:

```
def update_rank
  update = Boards::UpdateService.new
  update.execute(self)
end
```

**UPDATE**:

Calling `execute` will work for initialising simply because it updates user's `leaderboard` if it exists and creates it if it doesn't.

To initialise it properly you should consider invoking methods for creating the leaderbord for a user when he or she is being created.

Comment: Hmm, ok that makes sense...I'll try it out once I figure out how to get all the other user scores on it first...